# Surprising case where exception handling in async method does not catch the exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await, try-catch

My code combines async methods with exception handling. The code is very simple and all tasks are awaited and there are no `async void` methods:

```
async Task DoWorkSafelyWithStateMachine()
{
    try
    {
        await DoWorkThatMightThrowException();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("With state machine: " + exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Awaiting this method does not throw an exception because the exception was swallowed:

```
await DoWorkSafelyWithStateMachine(); // No exception thrown
```

However, the code does not always catch exceptions as it is supposed to do. The problem arises when the method is written in a slightly different way where no async state machine is created by the compiler:

```
Task DoWorkSafelyWithoutStateMachine()
{
    try
    {
        return DoWorkThatMightThrowException();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Without state machine: " + exception.Message);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The method is not decorated with `async` and nothing is awaited inside the method. Instead the task returned by the method inside `try` is returned to the caller. However, in my experience the magic of the compiler somehow still ensures that if the method inside `try` throws an exception it gets caught by the exception handler. Well, apparently that is not always true.

To test these two variations of the same method I let `DoWorkThatMightThrowException` throw an exception. If the method does not have to use `await` in the body of the method then it can be implemented either with or without an async state machine:

```
async Task DoWorkThatMightThrowExceptionWithStateMachine()
{
    throw new Exception("With state machine");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}

Task DoWorkThatMightThrowExceptionWithoutStateMachine()
{
    throw new Exception("Without state machine");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I have discovered that calling `DoWorkThatMightThrowExceptionWithStateMachine` from `DoWorkSafelyWithoutStateMachine` does not catch the exception thrown. The other three combinations do catch the exception. In particular, the version where no async state machines are involved in either method catches the exception and I have mistakenly extrapolated this observation with the unfortunate result that some of my code now has subtle errors.

```
                          | Throw + state machine | Throw - state machine |
--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
Try/catch + state machine |        Caught         |        Caught         |
Try/catch - state machine |      Not caught       |        Caught         |
```

Doing this experiment I have learned that I always have to `await` a task inside a `try` block (first line in table). However, I don't understand the inconsistency in the second row of the table. Please explain this behavior. Where is it documented? It is not easy to search for information about this. The more basic problem of exceptions being "lost" because tasks are not awaited will dominate the search results.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @Servy: I assumed that _I don't understand_ was in implied question. However, I have modified the phrasing a bit and also added a question mark.

Comment: Would be nice to see an [MCVE] with the above methods and how they are executed. Your code seems... weird.  You might be misunderstanding how tasks manage exceptions thrown *within them* (so to speak).  Hard to tell without putting all the pieces together, tho.

Comment: @Will: All the code is there. The only thing you have to do to execute it is to apply a bit of renaming to combine the various methods. There are four nearly identical cases combined and I didn't want to list them all copy-paste ready to not inflate my question with code.

Comment: The main point is method marked with 'async' (doesn't matter if it has await statements or not) will be rewritten by compiler to always return a Task. If exception is thrown (even before first await) - it will return task in faulted state, but still always a Task. And anyway, wrapping something that returns a Task in try catch without awaiting is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand the inconsistency in the second row of the table

The right side case (no state machines at all) is trivial:

- you call a method inside a `try/catch` block
- the method throws an exception
- your `catch` black catches it - nothing special

The left side is actually easy to understand, too:

- you call a method inside a `try/catch` block
- but this method is not what it seems, it has been converted to a state
  machine, so what it returns is a `Task` that represents the execution of the method's content as you implemented it<sup>(1)</sup>
- so as long as you don't `Wait` or `await` that returned `Task` or try to access its `Result` property, the exception is not (re-)thrown inside your `try` block.

---

<sup>(1) I wish my English was better to find a better and more exact description. As [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47891917/5528593) pointed out, in your example an already faulted `Task` is returned.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

The `catch` block will execute when an exception is thrown in the `try` block.  When you write `return DoWorkThatMightThrowExceptionWithStateMachine();` all the try block is doing is constructing a `Task` marked as faulted and returning it.  No exception is ever thrown, so no `catch` block is ever run.

If you await the faulted task it will re-throw that exception, so there is an exception being thrown.  When you call `DoWorkThatMightThrowExceptionWithoutStateMachine` the method itself is throwing an exception, not returning a faulted task, and so there's an exception being thrown in the `try` block.